# Matching two fields to find related results using MySQL fulltext?

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search

I have a blog table with two fields:

```
title  <--- plain text
body   <--- html format
```

Given a blog record, how can I find related blog posts by utilizing both the title and the body in a fulltext query?

Comment: have you searched something?

Answer (score 1):

try that:

```
  select *, MATCH (title, body) AGAINST ('some words' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as searched from table where MATCH(`title`, `body`) AGAINST('some words'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)DESC
```